# How do I efficiently map only those points that fall within the bounding box of a map?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code, where `mp` is a `Shapely` `Multipolygon` off of a `Fiona` box:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
minx, miny, maxx, maxy = mp.bounds
w, h = maxx - minx, maxy - miny
ax.set_xlim(minx, maxx)
ax.set_ylim(miny, maxy)
ax.set_aspect(1)
patches = []
for idx, p in enumerate(mp):
    patches.append(PolygonPatch(p, fc='#ffffff', ec='#000000', alpha=1., zorder=1))
ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(patches, match_original=True))
plt.show()
```

And I have a pandas dataframe with lots of Lat/Long pairs with a label.

```
> 0 -34.026810  -71.101670  A
> 1 -32.986970  -71.501580  G
> 2 -40.931400  -73.027190  C
```

However, not all points in the `df` "fall" into the bounds of the map. Question is: how do I efficiently map only those points in the bounding box of my map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it would be most efficient to filter the points on a pandas level. For that get the bounds of the Multipolygon using its `bounds` property and then filter the dataframe using

```
df[(df.lat > latmin) & (df.lat < latmax) 
   & (df.long > longmin) & (df.long < longmax)]
```

where I assume your latitude column is named `lat` and your longitude column `long`. `latmin`, `latmax` and so on are what you get from the multipolygon bounds.